# Passing Id In Button Click in JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

how do I pass the `id` to my event here?

```
            {
              var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
              var id = tr.children('td:eq(0)').text()
              data: null,
              render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<button id="btnAddNotes" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Add Notes</button>';
              }
            },
```

and I'm reading it like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAddNotes", function (e) {
 //here is where I want to see the id i'm passing
}
```

**EDIT**
This is how I construct the column, and I want to use the id of the row for the column `At Location` -> how would I set that up?

```
columns: [
{ 
    title: "At Location",
    data: "id" ,
    width: "10%",
    className: "text-center",
    render: function (data, type, full, meta){
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
    }
},
{
    title: "Notes",
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<button data-id="' +
    row. + // I want to use the At Location value
    '" class="btn" type="button">Add Notes</button>'; }
}
]
```

Comment: Two things to note here is that first, the top two lines will give an error - they need to be removed. And secondly, IDs must be unique - with that code all rows will have a button with the same ID. You could add the row number (third arg in the render() function) to the ID, or use a class instead.

Comment: @colin0117 - oh I didn't realize the `var xxx` lines would throw an error.  How would I write it properly?  Unique Id's that makes sense, i'll work on udpating that now --- I found this example, and it doesn't appear they are adding a unique id?  https://codepen.io/jeffld/pen/gdQoLb -> my goal here is to have a modal pop-up display with data that is relevant to the id of the row clicked (if that changes anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Use the DataTables API to populate the ID you want to use.

---

**Longer Explanation:**

You are already using the API in your [column render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function - so we can take advantage of that (I have simplified your HTML slightly):

```js
render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
  return '<button data-id="' + 
      meta.row + // the internal ID of the DataTable row
      '" class="btn" type="button">Add Notes</button>';
}
```

In this case I use `meta.row` to get the unique DataTables row index (which starts at 0 for the first row).

I assign it to the `data-id` attribute - but I could assign it to the `id` attribute also, since the value is guaranteed to be unique for each row (and therefore for each button).

I can access this using the following:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log( id );
});
```

---

If you want to populate the `data-id` attribute with an actual value from the data row, then you can use the `row` parameter instead of the `meta` parameter.

Here is a runnable demo, using an external Ajax data test source, courtesy of the `jsonpaceholder` web site:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    "columns": [{
        // https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return '<button data-id="' +
            row.title + // the value of the "TITLE" column from the data
            '" class="btn" type="button">Add Notes</button>';
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "User ID",
        "data": "userId"
      },
      {
        "title": "ID",
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title",
        "data": "title"
      }
    ]

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(id);
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

The above demo uses `row.title` in the `render` function, just as an example.

**Warning:** Depending on what you do with the selected data, you may run into problems. To be safe, you should probably only use a column where the values are guaranteed to be unique.

And you **must** guarantee uniqueness if you want to use the `id` attribute instead of a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: thank you for this sample.  I was wanting to use the id from the first column of the row as that is the Database Id and will always always be unique, plus it is what I'll be using in my where clause to query the database and pull in some additional info for the modal popup

Comment: OK - your question does not show us how that column is constructed by your DataTable, so I can't provide specific guidance on that (if you are stuck). You can add the following line to your render function: `console.log( row );`. That will show you whether your DataTable rows are JavaScript objects or arrays. From that you should be able to see how to access that data.

Comment: i edited my OP to illustrate better - sorry!

Comment: Try using `row.id` in the code where you build your button.

Comment: It is very difficult to read fragments of code in comments. You should clarify by editing your question. Having said that, it _looks_ as if your first column's data is identified by `id`. Therefore you can grab that in the render function of your _second_ column by using `row.id`. But like I say, you can see for yourself by using `console.log( row );`.

Comment: excellent - hopefully that better illustrates where I am stuck now :)

Comment: Right - use `row.id`. If that does not work, show us `console.log( row );` .

Comment: Glad it worked. Hopefully it also makes sense _why_ it worked. It can be a bit confusing, with all the values called `data` and `id` flying around...

Answer (score 3):

You can add it as a data- attribute.

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var id = tr.children('td:eq(0)').text()
{
  data: null,
  render: function(data, type, row) {
      return '<button id="btnAddNotes" type="button" data-id="' + id + '" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Add Notes</button>';
  }
}



$(document).on("click", "#btnAddNotes", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
})
```